# The horizontal gap/kern before the comma is too large with unicode-math

Tags: math-mode, punctuation, unicode-math, kerning

The following minimal example is stripped down from the sentence, “Let (, ≤) be a poset.”
Feeding `lualatex` or `xelatex` with

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
%\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\((T,{\le})\)
\end{document}
```

yields a relatively small gap between  and the comma, whereas using `unicode-math`, with or without the `[math-style=ISO]` (it doesn't matter), yields a gap larger by a factor of ≈1.196 for `lualatex` and ≈1.204 for `xelatex`:

[image: output for lualatex]

In case of the glyphs with lots of space in the right lower corner (, , , , , ), this increase by ≈ 20 % causes more pain than we already endure.
The documentation of unicode-math is silent about the commas completely. It's unclear to me whether the gap has increased because of Latin Modern Math, or whether unicode-math (whether intentionally or not) inserts additional horizontal space. Is it a bug or a feature?

In the first case: which purpose does it serve?

In the second case: Can this gap before the math commas be reduced (either in general or for the pairs “,”, “,”, “,”, “,”, “,”, and “,”) once for the whole document rather via `\mskip-1mu plus.5mu minus.5mu` each time?

Comment: it's much easier if you use `article` rather than `standalone` in such tests. `standalone` is ... complicated and introduces many artifacts that make tracing things hard

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Got it. With `standalone`, we can allow for smaller LaTeX input files because we don't need to add `\pagestyle{empty}` or pretend as if the page number were not printed. Also, visual comparisons are sometimes easier when the PDF outputs are visually small.

Comment: sure but I'm far more likely to add `\tracingall` and trace what tex is doing than look at the output for code posted here:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. I'll do better next time.

Answer (score 4):

The spacing is determined by the font used not by the tex macros

**Latin Modern Math OpenType**

This is with lualatex, xelatex log is different but identical space

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
\((T,{\le})\)
\end{document}
```

---

```
....\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 
....\kern1.48 (italic)
....\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 ,
```

**Latin Modern tfm**

pdflatex log

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
\((T,{\le})\)
\end{document}
```

---

```
....\kern1.3889
....\kern-0.55556
....\OML/lmm/m/it/10 ;
```

**Computer Modern tfm**

pdflatex log

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
\((T,{\le})\)
\end{document}
```

---

```
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 T
....\kern1.3889
....\kern-0.55556
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ;
```

**Latin Modern Math with italic correction mode 2**

Luatex offers three modes of handling italic correction,
Mode 2 here works better but note that it's a global change that may change  more than you want. Exactly what changes in each mode is not over documented in the luatex manual, use at own risk:-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\showoutput
\mathitalicsmode=2
\begin{document}
\((T,{\le})\)
\end{document}
```

---

```
....\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 
....\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 ,
```

Comment: Thank you! So in other words and up to the tolerance of 0.1 pt, unicode-math with Latin Modern Math OpenType does not introduce a negative kern which we obtain when using tfm, right? I'm still unsure about the purpose (feature) or the absence thereof (bug).

Comment: @AlMa1r the font designer has to take a manual design choice to adjust the letters between any two characters in a font, especially in opentype fonts there are a lot of pairs to consider and lots of room for different people to have different judgements or maintainers just to get tired and not add some or ....  but tex always believes the font. In luatex you can modify the font metrics and add kern pairs on the fly but in xetex for math mode fixing it really would mean forking the font and modifying the font to have more kern pairs

Comment: I see. I suspect that “just to get tired and not add some [pairs]” is likely. :-( Unless someone provides another answer here :-).

Comment: @AlMa1r seems to be the day for modifying answers after second thoughts, see update

Comment: For xelatex, I modified the font by inserting a subtable in Element > Font Info > Lookups > GPOS > Math kern and let the kerning be set automatically. It looks great in fontforge: https://ibb.co/CVXYHWW .  However, it seems that xelatex ignores this table when in math mode.

Comment: `\mathitalicsmode=2` does a good job for this minimal example. For larger texts, I still have to check …. In the luatex manual, I see “the old school font code path” in § 7.5.5. Are any hyphens missing? Is, e.g., “the old-school font-code path” meant? Or should the words be combined differently? (Off-topic: the difference between values 0 and 1 on the given example with Cambria is not visible.)

Comment: yes old-school refers to the code path not the fonts. But in any case (I think)  it's just a polite way of saying "the opentype math spec is too vague, fonts are too inconsistent and here's an interface to some internal parameters that may or may not help" so it doesn't matter much how you parse the english:-) @AlMa1r

Comment: I have a possibility to fork off the font and change the tables (as noticed above), so the value 2 might hypothetically help.